# Load assembly to another domain in C#. Memory leak or not?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, marshalling

I have some application (dialog window + dll) what loads some external .dll library and analyse methods inside it. In fact in this part I need to get methods with specific attribute.

I have "Reload Library" button and after clicking on it next are performed:

1. Opens file dialog and we select external library to analyse
2. At application we have folder where we move this external dll. Before it we clean all files form this folder
3. New application domain is created after copy. If previous domain is was not unloaded (I use domain with the same name for all different assemblies) I unload it before creating new one with the same name. Another application domain has proxy inherited from MarshalByRefObject and object has infinite lifetime.
4. Copy of assembly loads to this new domain.

All of this was working perfect till I look to Task Manager to check how much memory uses my application :) So every time I click on reload library it takes more and more memory. I opened performance analyser and start investigate Private Bytes of my application.

Here is what I have
[image]

So when I do nothing everything is OK and line is smooth. Than I start to click "Reload Library" button a lot of times and we can see that number of bytes increasing. It seems that memory leak is really present in my application. But after some time if I click reload again I see than great downturn and all memory what was allocated during my experiment is released.

Why? I cannot understand is it normal behaviour or my application has memory leak?

Comment: Do you call GC.Collect() after unloading the AppDomain ?

Comment: no. It is created like this 
(InOtherAppDomain)dom.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(typeof(InOtherAppDomain).Assembly.FullName, typeof(InOtherAppDomain).FullName);
and unloaded 
AppDomain.Unload(dom);

Comment: Clearly you do **not** have a leak, it could never fall back like that if it were a real leak.  You are simply misunderstanding how memory management works in Windows, it is a lot more sophisticated than a simple number like Private Bytes could ever show.  It is simply not in a hurry to uncommit virtual memory address space, keeping it around for later use instead.  Which is fine, it is virtual, it doesn't cost anything.  Ping-ponging allocations is work that doesn't accomplish anything.

Comment: It seems that call GC.Collect() after  AppDomain.Unload(dom); helps =)

Answer (score 1):

Check AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() when you do some reloading and verify that they are not always getting loaded multiple times into to the runtime AppDomain.

Comment: Also came across this post.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/56a79592-4e11-4f4b-9b0b-73905b56bfe0/how-to-load-an-assembly-in-new-appdomain and the only difference I notice there is on the dom.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap passes Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName vs you have typeof(InOtherAppDomain).Assembly.FullName